# C++ pass by value / by reference function overload

Tags: c++, c++11

There are 2 function overloads:

```
MyClass do_something(MyClass param);
const MyClass& do_something(const MyClass& param);
```

Then I do:

```
MyClass c1 {"c1"};
do_something(c1);  // I want this to be used by value overload
do_something(c1);  // this to be used by reference overload
```

Is there any special way to explicitly specify that argument is passed by value or by reference?

For move semantic there is `std::move()` I wonder if there is anything like `std::copy()` `std::ref` for my case?

P.S. It's not to be used in real program, just checking out by myself the difference of passing arguments, returning values and their behaviour in different ways and have all functions with the same name:

```
// pass by value (copy)
MyClass do_something(MyClass param) {
    cout << "do_something(MyClass param)" << endl;
    param.i = 100;
    return param;
}

// !!! Your normal habit when passing an argument to a function should be to pass by const reference. (thinking in c++)
// pass by reference (reference)
const MyClass& do_something(const MyClass& param) { // doesn't allow to modify the object
    cout << "do_something(MyClass& param)" << endl;
    return param;
}

// pass by move semantic (move)
MyClass&& do_something(MyClass&& param) {
    cout << "do_something(MyClass&& param)" << endl;
    param.name += "__after_do_something(MyClass&& param)";
    param.i = 100;
    return move(param);
}

// pass by pointer (reference)
MyClass* do_something(MyClass* const param) { // allows to modify object, but not pointer (address)
    cout << "do_something(MyClass* const param)" << endl;
    param->i = 100;
    // (*param).i = 100;  // the same as above
    return param;
}
```

Comment: Not possible, and makes no sense. If you need to indicate, every time, which of the overloaded functions to take, you defeat the purpose of overloading.

Comment: If functions in question were templates and MyClass a template parameter the result could be disambiguated on the basis of whether MyClass was copyable or not.

Comment: @n.m. he said as he completely disregarded move semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve an overload ambiguity by casting to the relevant function pointer type (it's one of the rare cases where the type of an expression is determined by outer context, instead of being built up from inside):

```
struct MyClass { char const* s; };

MyClass do_something(MyClass) { return MyClass(); }
const MyClass& do_something(const MyClass& param) { return param; }

auto main() -> int
{
    MyClass c1 {"c1"};
    static_cast<MyClass(*)(MyClass)>( do_something )( c1 );         // Value overload
    static_cast<MyClass const&(*)(MyClass const&)>( do_something )( c1 );  // Ref overload
}
```

But in practice you should just name the functions differently, or use tie-breaker arguments or argument types, i.e., designing the functions for *explicit* choice of function.

I would name them differently because they do different things, so it indicates the Wrong Thing™ to have the same name for them.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any special way to explicitly specify that argument is passed by value or by reference?

No, but there are workaround.

- With template method and specialization, you may explicitly tell which version you want:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  T do_something(T);

  template<>
  MyClass do_something(MyClass) { std::cout << "value" << std::endl; }

  template<>
  const MyClass& do_something(const MyClass&)
  {
      std::cout << "reference" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  And then call it:

  ```
  do_something<MyClass>(c); // value
  do_something<const MyClass&>(c); // reference
  do_something(c); // value
  ```

  [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/D35WnR)
- But it would be simpler/cleaner to create overload with explicit tag:

  ```
  struct by_value{};
  struct by_ref{};

  MyClass do_something(MyClass, by_value) { std::cout << "value" << std::endl; }

  const MyClass& do_something(const MyClass&, by_ref)
  {
      std::cout << "reference" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  And call it

  ```
  do_something(c, by_value{}); // value
  do_something(c, by_ref{}); // reference
  ```

Comment: Nice thing with templates. The second option - it's will be simpler to rename the function. But as an option - should work too. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any special way to explicitly specify that argument is passed by value or by reference?

Yes. If it is not copyable (i.e., deleted or private copy constructor) it can only be passed by reference.

Comment: Maybe you should test your hypothesis first.

Comment: Right, so that does not provide a means to disambiguate between the two overloads. It just results in a compiler error.